# How to sign out using the POST /api/auth/signout endpoint with Next Auth?

Tags: node.js, next.js, next-auth

This [`Reddit`](https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/szcfuq/how_to_server_side_signout_in_nextauth/) post suggests to make "an api call in signOut event. The backend handled the rest of it."

Sure, so let's write it :

```
await fetch('/api/auth/signout', { method: "POST" });
```

Except the request is redirected through a `302` to `GET /api/auth/signout?csrf=true` which, in turn, redirects to `GET /auth/sign-out`, my custom sign out page; the user is not signed out.

The [documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/rest-api) does specify that the "POST submission requires CSRF token from /api/auth/csrf", however there is no example usage of this.

Hitting `/api/auth/csrf` I get a JSON response, so I simply used that value as the body of the initial `POST` request:

```
await fetch('/api/auth/signout', {
  method: "POST",
  body: await fetch('/api/auth/csrf').then(rs => rs.text())
});
```

Which does make a request, then adds a payload of `{"csrfToken":...}`, but the same redirects, and the user is still not signed out.

My goal is to sign-out and not be redirected when calling the initial `POST` request. Is that possible?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `signOut({ redirect: false })`? See https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#using-the-redirect-false-option-1.

Comment: @juliomalves yes, because that API is available only on the client side, where Next Auth is available. These requests are made from third party apps, where there is no Next Auth API's available, to delete the session cookie from the authentication app.

Comment: I see, it wasn't clear to me that the request was happening from a third-party app. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Azure-AD is a common platform used for Auth  using NextAuth 

I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was close. This is the request that ended up working :

```
await fetch('/api/auth/signout?callbackUrl=/api/auth/session', {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
  body: await fetch('/api/auth/csrf').then(rs => rs.text())
});
```

The callback only serves to not be redirected to the sign in page, the default behavior.

The `Content-type` is JSON even if the body is a string; this tells Next.js how to parse the content of the body.

Answer (score 0):

Use the signIn callback and return a url/string.

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  callbacks: {
    signIn({ user }) {
      if (user?.email !== 'my-email@gmail.com') {
        return '/';
      }

      return true;
    },
  },
};
```

However, my recommendation (and next-auth's) is to return them to an error page. This will happen by default if you return false.

```
signIn({ user }) {
  return user?.email === 'my-email@gmail.com';
},
```

Here's their documentation if you want to read further. [next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#sign-in-callback)